I have staked PYTH and I want to withdraw it but it's in a HACKED wallet
Can you help me what to do with a hacked wallet. It automatically drains the wallet whenever I send solana in it. Is there a way I can Unstake PYTH to another wallet?

Yes this is possible. You just need to do all the instructions in one transaction (create ATAs, unstake, transfer from your hacked wallet to a safe wallet, close ATAs) and pay the fee from the safeWallet. Assuming your account is still owned by the System Program at least.
